# Заставить chrome сохранить html тот который обработанный по F12

Tags: python

Новичок в python:
Есть задача распарсить один сайт.  Но сайт вероятно защищен от парсинга. Так как код возвращаем не содержит нужной стурктуры.
Зато задача работает если на странице нажать F12 скопировать этот код в файл и его распарсить, то все работает. 
Нужно сохранить то что выдает chrome по F12.

как вообще это сделать? Заставить Chrome сохранить страницу которую он отображает в отладчике.

спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) или [request-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) модули для парсинга, сайт, который Вы парсите, скорее всего сгенерирован javascript'ом

Comment: да вы правы. А как парсить такие сайты? я сделал через webdriver запускаю сайт сохраняю драйвером страницу в файл а потом файл уже обрабатываю. Это медленней но работает. Есть более красивый способ? Спасибо.

Comment: `request-html` и есть более простой и быстрый способ. Чем он вам не подходит @Manul74 ?

Comment: Да. это помогло. Не знал про эту(request-htm) библиотеку. сначала не обратил внимания что request и reauest-html разные вещи

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался сам

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('xxxxxx')

with open('page.html', 'w+',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
    f.close()

driver.close()

а потом читаем из файла
```